# Add JLayeredPane Swing to JPanel

Tags: java, swing, imageicon, jlayeredpane

I have a "Illegal Component Position" in my method, have you an idea why i have this ?

I execute this methode for placing a ImageIcon and also set Z axis for an ImageIcon.

```
    public void Placer(ImageIcon a, int x, int y, int z) {
    JPanel panel = (JPanel) this.getContentPane();

    JLayeredPane lp =  getLayeredPane();
    lp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));

    panel.setLayout(null);
    JLabel image = new JLabel(a);
    panel.add(image);
    Dimension size = image.getPreferredSize();
    image.setBounds(x, y, size.width, size.height);
    lp.add(panel, new Integer(z));

}
```

When i call

```
        for (int y = 0,y1=0; y < 910; y += 35,y1++) {
        for (int x = 0,x1=0; x < 910; x += 35,x1++) {
            Placer(this.affichageBatiment[x1][y1], x, y, -5);
            Placer(this.affichageAgentEquipe1[x1][y1], x, y,-3);
            Placer(this.affichageAgentEquipe2[x1][y1],x,y,-2);

        }
    }
```

PS : all the 2d arrays are arrays of ImageIcon
and i have this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: illegal component position
at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1098)
at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.addImpl(JLayeredPane.java:231)
at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:975)
at Fenetre.Placer(Fenetre.java:69)
at Fenetre.afficherTout(Fenetre.java:146)
at Fenetre.<init>(Fenetre.java:54)
at Tournoi.LancerTournoi(Tournoi.java:34)
at Main.main(Main.java:14)
```

Comment: Please add full stacktrace and actual values for x, y and z.

Comment: @Würgspaß it's better now?

Comment: Still no stack trace of the exception.

Comment: @Würgspaß Sorry, voila

Answer (score 0):

The method you want to call in your last line of `Placer`-method is `Component.add(Component comp, int index);` With `index` being:

> index - the position at which to insert the component, or -1 to append
>   the component to the end

So, with `lp.add(panel, -1);` **you get rid of the Exception**.

I am not sure, why you call it with wrapper object `Integer` but please **note that in effect you are calling** `Component.add(Component comp, Object constraints);` because `Integer` is an `Object`. Here, the object is supposed to be

> constraints - an object expressing layout constraints for this
>   component

And because `Integer` is not a valid layout constraints object, the  `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown.

Comment: Yeah, i get rid of the Exception when i call my method Placer like that : 
"Placer(this.affichageBatiment[x1][y1], x, y, 0);" but when i call my method Placer with : Placer(this.affichageBatiment[x1][y1], x, y, -1); it doesn't work

Comment: But that is not what I wrote, is it?. In _any case_ you have to change the code in `Placer`. This line `lp.add(panel, new Integer(z));` **cannot work as intended**, no matter what value z hactually has. Either pass an `int` (not `Integer`) or pass a valid object (depending on what you want to archieve).